# Como rotacionar uma matriz uma posição por vez em c?

Tags: c

Preciso criar um algoritmo em C para rotacionar em sentido anti-horário, uma posição na matriz 7x7. Porém, deve rotacionar, quantas vezes o usuário decidir. E só rotacionar a linha e coluna de fora...
Porém meu programa só rotaciona 1 vez certo, e ainda não todas as colunas.

Para isso fiz um for das linhas e colunas do exterior da matriz, e fui incrementando...

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        matriz2[i][j] = matriz[i][j];
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        
        if(i == 6){
            matriz2[i][j+1] = matriz[i][j];
        }
        if(j == 0){
            matriz2[i+1][j] = matriz[i][j];
        }
        if(i == 0){
            matriz2[i][j-1] = matriz[i][j];
        }
        if(j == 6){
            matriz2[i-1][j] = matriz[i][j];
        }    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3):

Boa noite, isso que esta a falar tem a ver com Algebra linear, e é transposição de uma matriz(trocar as linhas pelas colunas)...

Exprimenta multiplicar a tua matriz por uma matriz identidade transposta

M.Identidade transposta 7x7=
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0]

Lembrando que a multiplicação entre matrizes é Linha da primeira matriz pela coluna da 2 matriz... (aconselho a investigar sobre este assunto), transpores 2x a mesma matriz obtens a matriz original.

Boa sorte e boa programação.